# Converting data type varchar to numeric throws

Tags: sql, azure

I'm working with data factory flow. In my input CSV file I have numbers like `10617,9   -3360`, in my mapping I did `decimal -> decimal` (my output SQL DB), but I it gave me this error message:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

```
source(output(

    {pre-taxe amount} as decimal(20,5),
    {amount including taxe} as decimal(20,5),

),
allowSchemaDrift: true,
validateSchema: false,
preferredIntegralType: 'integer',
preferredFractionalType: 'decimal') ~> sourceInvoices

    sourceInvoices sink(input(
    AmountExcludingTax as decimal(20,5),
    AmountIncludingTax as decimal(20,5),


),
```

What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: You should add more information to this question. Maybe some important code snippet or ss of what can you see.

Comment: yes , i had rror converting data type varchar to numeric. like error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used below for my decimal mapping in ADF.

[image]

In The Table column

[image]

Comment: its working for me and my data is loading everyday.

Comment: u did (string---> double) should i modify my script sql to double? is that right?

Comment: i just added another pic

Answer (score 1):

Probably the issue here is the difference in the decimal separator used in the file (`,`) and ADF (`.`). Because of this, ADF cannot parse the value as a valid numeric value.

As far as I know there's no out-of-the-box way to convert this in ADF. The solution would probably be to either change the system outputting the CSV or parsing the values as strings first, replacing commas with periods.

**EDIT:**
If the error message it's giving is

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

then it's in there as a string value somewhere, and you're trying to convert it to a numerical value. That's not working because of the explanation above: if the decimal separator is the period (.) and the thousand separator is the comma (,) the value `10617,9` is NOT a valid numerical value.

If you replace the comma with the period, which would give `10617.9`, you should be good to go converting it into a numerical value.

Comment: i edit my post perhaps u can understand more my problem thnks

Comment: perhaps, but how can i define if (,) or (.)?

Comment: "but how can I define if (,) or (.)" => You cannot. That's why you need to *replace* the comma with a period before converting the value. Have a look at my updated answer

Comment: i did it i don't get the error anymore  but i get nothing (null) however the value existe in my csv file